# SQLite stuck on the SQLite.trampoline() method

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I wrote a program in java which uses SQLite(v056).

I query the DB a lot of times, using a Statement (calling it's `executeQuery()` method) and it works fine.

After some time, it stucks on the method `trampoline()`.

The query executed in this time was:

```
select * from defs where word like 'AA' and size=2;
```

I really don't know what's wrong, and why it is stucked.

Did some of you have the same problem? Do you know how to solve it?

Thanks ahead!

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what the situation is on the Android platform, but the [Zentus SQLiteJDBC driver](http://www.zentus.com/sqlitejdbc/) is based on SQLite 3.6.14.2 which is over two years old, not to mention that SQLite 3.6.x has been superceded by SQLite 3.7 for quite some time now.

Perhaps you could try the [Xerial SQLiteJDBC driver](http://www.xerial.org/trac/Xerial/wiki/SQLiteJDBC) which is more recent, although it has not been updated to the latest SQLite version either.

EDIT:

1. Apparently the `trampoline()` method is part of the [NestedVM](http://nestedvm.ibex.org/) version of the SQLite library that is used by SQLiteJDBC when it does not have a native SQLite library for your platform. The NestedVM implementation seems to push the limits of the JVM and it will be extremely difficult to debug - you'd be better off making sure a native library is available.
2. If you are programming for Android, then you should not use SQLiteJDBC at all. Android has its own [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html) for SQLite DB handling. A tutorial for using SQLite in Android can be found [here](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidSQLite/article.html).